# Python Source com subprocess

Tags: python, terminal

Estou tentando rodar uma linha de comando no terminal através de um script em python.
A linha de comando é a seguinte:

```
vcftools --vcf <arquivo.vcf> --extract-FORMAT-info GT --out <arquivo sem extensão>
```

Para tal tenho as seguintes linhas:

```
import os
import subprocess
import getopt
import sys

def main(argv):
    inputfile_1 = ''
    outputfile = ''
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(
            argv, "hi:o:", ["ifile=", "ofile="])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        print ('test.py -i <inputfile_1> -o <outputfile>')
        sys.exit(2)
    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt == '-h':
            print ('test.py -i <inputfile_1> -o <outputfile>')
            sys.exit()
        elif opt in ("-i", "--ifile"):
            inputfile_1 = arg
        elif opt in ("-o", "--ofile"):
            outputfile = arg
    print ('O arquivo de input i: %s' % (inputfile_1))
    print ('O arquivo de output: %s' % (outputfile))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])


proc = subprocess.Popen(["vcftools --vcf" + inputfile_1 + "--extract-FORMAT-info GT --out" + outputfile], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(out, err) = proc.communicate()
```

E o erro que estou obtendo:

```
guido-5:vcfx_statistics_gvcf_herc2 debortoli$ python vcftools.py -i herc2.gvcf.statistics_checkad.vcf -o test_vcf_ad

O arquivo de input i: herc2.gvcf.statistics_checkad.vcf
O arquivo de output: test_vcf_ad

Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "vcftools.py", line 30, in <module>
        proc = subprocess.Popen(["vcftools --vcf" + inputfile_1 + "--extract-FORMAT-info GT --out" + outputfile], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    NameError: name 'inputfile_1' is not defined
```

Pelo jeito o erro está na atribuição de `inputfile_1` ao `sys.argv[1]`...

Qualquer ajuda será bem-vinda.

Comment: O tau variável input_file1 só é visível dentro da função main, deves proc=... também dentro desta, no fim talvez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que a variável `inputfile_1` que você usa em `subprocess.Popen` foi definida apenas no escopo da definição main. Para funcionar você só precisaria declará-la como global ou colocar esse trecho de código dentro do escopo da definição main.